# Getting PHP extension "gd" and Database support disabled error

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Drupal 8.7.3 on my windows machine through the Xampp (PHP 7.3.6). But I am getting following errors:

## Errors:

Please see the screenshot:
https://snag.gy/06sMEa.jpg

## Tried to attempt:

I tried to do the following but couldn't resolve it:

1- I have copied php.ini under the root of my drupal folder and made sure that extensions are enabled. and I made sure the default php.ini has the same extensions enabled as well.
Please see the screenshot: https://snag.gy/nN8BGA.jpg

2- I have also downloaded the php_gd2.dll and php_gd.dll and put them to the /ext folder as well. please see the screenshot: https://snag.gy/RHqrlI.jpg

My problem still the same. Can you please help me to sort this issue out.

This is my phpinfo() result about the extensions:
https://snag.gy/ifsIjo.jpg

Also, see the extension path:
https://snag.gy/Jlcw01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Long ago I came to my belief that even when a web engine says it can run on Windows... avoid if possible. Follow the herd.

These are not Drupal issues. This is an environment issue. You would probably be better off using Laravel's homestead virtual machine to host your Drupal site locally (and it would be on a linux environment inside of your windows environment).

Or if you want to focus on development and non system administration tasks, find a hosting provider that will tackle things like this for you. I have hosting companies that I would just email them requests to install the missing modules and they would do it for me.

Comment: Just use a Docker solution or Acquia Dev Desktop. But yeah, Windows is not a favorable environment. At a minimum you should be virtualizing on Windows so you aren’t bogged down installing PHP etc on the host.